# validate multipe tablename and Error handling using sas macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a main code file and macro code file and multiple tables and I want to validate the table _name and the same for column names, should be alphabets and underscore only by using macro and with do loop and I want that when I call my macro in the main file, if error occurs it generate error code and return code to macro code.

Main Code

```
/*******import mapping excel file********/
 proc import datafile="/home/viadmin/casuser/mapping.xlsx"
 out= work.mapping
 dbms=xlsx
 replace;
 sheet=sheet1;
 run;

/* update bank_key value */
data mapping;
set mapping;
if target_column='bank_key'
then mapping='0';
if target_column='change_begin_date' then mapping='%SYSFUNC(DATETIME())';
if target_column='change_end_date' then mapping="'01JAN5999:00:00:00'DT";
if target_column='current_ind' then mapping='"Y"';
if target_column = "bank_status_desc" then delete;
run;
/**create list of source and target tables to be loaded***/ 

proc sql;
    select distinct source_table into:source_table
    from mapping
    where source_table is not null;
run;
%put &source_table;

proc sql;
    select distinct target_table, mapping, target_column,count(*) 
        into :target_table,
        :mapping_func separated by ' ' ,
        :trgt_col separated by ' ',
        :count
    from mapping;
run;

%check_table;

%createTable;

proc sql ;
      select compress(put(max(BANK_KEY), best32.))
         into :etls_maxkey
        from amlcore.&target_table;
      quit;

/* %scdType2Loader; */
```

Macro code

```
 %macro check_table;
  /* Check if the table name is empty. */
  %if (&source_table.="" ) %then 
    %do;
        %put "Error: Table name cannot be empty.";
        %return;
    %end;

  /* Check if the table name contains any special characters. */
  %let i = 1;
  %let l=%length(&source_table.);

  %do i=1 %to &l.;
    /* Check if the current character is a letter or underscore. */
    %if %substr(&source_table., &i, 1) ne " " 
    and %substr(&source_table., &i, 1) ne "_" 
    and %substr(&source_table., &i, 1) ne "." 
    and  %substr(&source_table., &i, 1) ne "0-9 "
    and %substr(&source_table., &i, 1) ne "$/,!@#%^&*" 
    %then %do;
      %put "Error: Table name can only contain letters and underscores.";
      %return;
    %end;
    %if &syscc gt 0 %then %do;
    %abort cancel;
    %end;
    %let i = &i + 1;
  %end;
   
  /* The table name is valid. */
  %put "Table name is valid.";
%mend check_table;

 %check_table;
```

Comment: Why not let the loader run with the supplied mapping and fail with an ERROR: when the mapping is invalid?  In SAS batch mode use system option ERRORABEND to halt the session when an ERROR occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if a string is a valid SAS name then just use the NVALID() function.

Example:

```
134  data test;
135    input name $40.;
136    length=lengthn(name);
137    nvalid = nvalid(name,'v7');
138    put nvalid= length= name=:$quote.;
139  cards;

nvalid=1 length=3 name="abc"
nvalid=0 length=3 name="123"
nvalid=0 length=0 name=""
nvalid=0 length=5 name="x y z"
nvalid=0 length=33 name="this_name_is_going_to_be_too_long"
```